# Rails 4. Different routing for few models (relatd and not)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, seo

I am now working on website SEO optimization and what I am required to do is proper routing for links to be very seo friendly. I have read lots of information about routing, but it messed up in my head and I stuck.

So I have Store model which belongs to StoreType model, to City model and District model + District belongs_to :city.

I need to have routes like this:

```
/stores/store_type_name/                - store_type 'show' action(list of stores by type)
/stores/city_name/store_type_name/          - store_type 'show' action(list of stores by city&type)
/stores/city_name/district_name/store_type_name/    - store_type 'show' action(list of stores by city&district&type)
/stores/city_name/store_type_name/store_name        - store 'show' action
```

The only solution I came up with for now is:
Routes.rb

```
namespace :stores do 
  get ':transliterated', to: 'store_types#show'
  get ':transliterated/:name_en', to: 'store_types#city'
  get ':transliterated/:name_en/:id', to: 'store_types#district'
end
```

With controller like this:

```
def district
  @store_type = StorerType.find_by_transliterated(params[:transliterated])
  @city = City.find_by_name_en(params[:name_en])
  @district = District.find_by_id(params[:id])

  if @store_type && @city && @district
    stores = @store_type.stores.where(city_id:@city.id)
    @stores = stores.where(district_id:@district.id)
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

That works well but 1) I can not now add route for last example(store show page) as route is looking for :transliterated params in that namespace and redirects if record is not found. 2) I understand that this solution is bad and can be done much better, I just do not know how. Give me an advice please.

PS. Actually there is routing implemented on the site already so I am looking for the solution for those 4 urls listed above only, without touching anything else there.

Answer (score 1):

**Resourceful**

Firstly, let me define the basis of all your routing for you...

Rails' routing structure is known as being *resourceful* - meaning based *around* resources / objects. As with Ruby being an [object-orientated language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), Rails is an object-orientated framework; the routes are no exception to this:

[image]

This means anything you do with your routes **has** to be resource-based, as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :stores do
   resources :store_types, only: [:show], path: "" do #-> domain.com/stores/:id -> store_types#show
      get :name_en, action: :city #-> domain.com/stores/:store_type_id/:name_en
      get :name_en/:id, action: :district #-> domain.com/stores/:store_type_id/:name_en/:id
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to send the traffic directly to your `store_types` controller without having all sorts of crazy routes all over the place

--

**`friendly_id`**

Something else to consider is a gem called [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

`friendly_id` basically allows you to define / call routes with [`slugs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL), rather than `id`s. The difference is that the routes remain the same - it's the *data*, and the handling of that data, which changes

Typically in Rails, you'll create routes like this: `domain.com/controller/:id`

When you send people to links, they'll hit `domain.com/controller/1` for example. Friendly_ID basically facilities the ability to send people to `domain.com/controller/your_name`, handling it in exactly the same way as you would with an ID:

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
Class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @model = Model.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank You for this example, it helped me to understand routes little bit better. But I still have the problem of creating routes for `/stores/city_name/store_type_name/store_name` - my store 'show' action. When I try to nest it in my 'stores' namespace, my controller checks it for StoreType params and redirects. how can I get exactly this path for `/stores/city_name/store_type_name/store_name`?

ps: Yes, I know about `friendly_id gem`, that is great tool for making life little bit easuer, but in can not help me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some static strings in the urls to help to identify the actions, for examples:

```
namespace :stores do 
  get 'type/:transliterated', to: 'store_types#show'
  get 'type/:transliterated/city/:name_en', to: 'store_types#city'
  get ':transliterated/:name_en/:id', to: 'store_types#district'
end
```